# What are the dimension of View Controller in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, coordinate-systems

As you can see the frame with X=0,Y=209 Width = 600 **units** and Height = 391 **units**. 
I want to know what is ACTUALLY type of unit they are. i.e. are they **points** or **pixels** or what exactly? This question arises from the situation that if I want to move/slide down/set a sub-View in View Controller using storyboard **P** **pixels** down from top ? than what should I set the value of y-coordinate in that picture below which have currently 209 **units** in that settings?

[image]

Comment: In points. It doesn't care about pixels (retina or not).

Answer (score 1):

This is in points and not pixels. And doesn't take into consideration if the device is retina supported or not.

Comment: Thanks, but if i have dimensions in Pixels, how do i deal it with i.e. reflecting it properly in storyboard!!

Comment: @Divjyot: Take the large design and check if the size in pixels is for retina or not, and decides by 2 if needed.